# Using GDAL_Translater to convert and append TIF files into sqlite database - ERROR 6: New data has not the same SRS as existing data

Tags: gdal-translate

I have a number of TIF files provided by Ordnance Survey (OS OpenMap Local) that I am trying to add to a sqlite database. The first line in my code creates the sqlite database and adds the first TIF but then then all the following lines produce the error below:

```
ERROR 6: New data has not the same SRS as existing data
```

These are the command lines I'm running within the SDKShell command window for GDAL release-1928-x64-gdal-3-3-1-mapserver-7-6-4:

```
gdal_translate -of Rasterlite -co "DRIVER=PNG" "c:\os\OS Open Map - Local (Raster)\se\se80se.tif" RASTERLITE:"C:\ConnectDBs\OpenMapLocal.sqlite",table=OpenMapLocal -expand RGB
gdal_translate -of Rasterlite -co "DRIVER=PNG" "c:\os\OS Open Map - Local (Raster)\se\se80sw.tif" RASTERLITE:"C:\ConnectDBs\OpenMapLocal.sqlite",table=OpenMapLocal -expand RGB
gdal_translate -of Rasterlite -co "DRIVER=PNG" "c:\os\OS Open Map - Local (Raster)\se\se90sw.tif" RASTERLITE:"C:\ConnectDBs\OpenMapLocal.sqlite",table=OpenMapLocal -expand RGB
gdal_translate -of Rasterlite -co "DRIVER=PNG" "c:\os\OS Open Map - Local (Raster)\sk\sk99sw.tif" RASTERLITE:"C:\ConnectDBs\OpenMapLocal.sqlite",table=OpenMapLocal -expand RGB
```

I have used similar command lines to convert other OS products that has been successful. I have tried specifying the SRS in the command line but still get the same error. I have searched online and can't find anything about this error.

Does anyone know how I can get these TIF files into the sqlite database?

Answer (score 0):

OS have a bad habit of assuming that everyone (including GDAL) knows that their data is shipped as EPSG:27700 - but you actually need to tell GDAL (and most everyone else) so add `-s_srs epsg:277000` to your command line.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I have tried that and still get the same errorr.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why this works but I have found that by first building a virtual table from the TIF files using gdalbuildvrt I am then able to successfully build a sqlite database from the vrt using gdal_translate.